# Where does Kubeflow pipeline look for packages in `packages_to_install`?

Tags: python, kubeflow, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow-pipelines

I am using Kubeflow Pipelines in Vertex AI to create my ML pipeline and has beeen able to use standard packaged in Kubeflow component using the below syntax

```
@component(
   # this component builds an xgboost classifier with xgboost
   packages_to_install=["google-cloud-bigquery", "xgboost", "pandas", "sklearn", "joblib", "pyarrow"],
   base_image="python:3.9",
   output_component_file="output_component/create_xgb_model_xgboost.yaml"
)
def build_xgb_xgboost(project_id: str,
                     data_set_id: str,
                     training_view: str,
                     metrics: Output[Metrics],
                     model: Output[Model]
):
```

Now I need to add my custom python module in `packages_to_install` . Is there a way to do it? For this I need to understand where does KFP look for packages when installing those on top of base_image.
I understand this can be achieved using a custom base_image where I build the base_image with my python module in it. But it seems like an overkill for me and would prefer to specify python module where applicable in the component specification
Something like below

```
@component(
   # this component builds an xgboost classifier with xgboost
   packages_to_install=["my-custom-python-module","google-cloud-bigquery", "xgboost", "pandas", "sklearn", "joblib", "pyarrow"],
   base_image="python:3.9",
   output_component_file="output_component/create_xgb_model_xgboost.yaml"
)
def build_xgb_xgboost(project_id: str,
                     data_set_id: str,
                     training_view: str,
                     metrics: Output[Metrics],
                     model: Output[Model]
):
```

Comment: After seeing some documents `packages_to_install` also accepts a full GitHub path, for instance `'git+https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines#egg=kfp&subdirectory=sdk/python'`. So, you could upload your module to GitHub and use it as described before. Does this work for you?

Comment: It's always useful to look at the generated `component.yaml` file. They are pretty readable.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, the step will install the package at the runtime when executing the component. This requires a package to be hosted in a location that can be accessed by the runtime environment later.

Given that, you need to upload the package to a location that can be accessed later, e.g. git repository as Jose mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

> For this I need to understand where does KFP look for packages when installing those on top of base_image.

What you specified in `packages_to_install` is passed to `pip install` command, so it looks for packages from PyPI.
You can also install a package from a source control as `pip` supports it. See examples: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-vcs

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this

With KFP SDK 1.8.12, Kubeflow allows you to specify custom `pip_index_url`
See [Kubeflow feature request](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/6810)

With this feature, I can install my custom python module like this

```
@component(
   # this component builds an xgboost classifier with xgboost
   pip_index_urls=[CUSTOM_ARTEFACT_REPO, "https://pypi.python.org/simple"],
   packages_to_install=["my-custom-python-module","google-cloud-bigquery", "xgboost", "pandas", "sklearn", "joblib", "pyarrow"],
   base_image="python:3.9",
   output_component_file="output_component/create_xgb_model_xgboost.yaml"
)
def build_xgb_xgboost(project_id: str,
                     data_set_id: str,
                     training_view: str,
                     metrics: Output[Metrics],
                     model: Output[Model]
):
```